# How to install separate+ gimp-plugin for cmyk support?

Tags: software-installation, plugins, gimp, cmyk

In order to open CMYK photoshop files, I want to install the separate+ plugin for gimp. 
Since for building separate+ from sources it is required editing the makefile by hand(?), I was hoping for an ubuntu package. I installed gimp-plugin-registry via apt-get, which is supposed to contain separate+. After installing it, gimp has many new plugins enabled, but still doesn't have cmyk mode nor does it open cmyk psd files. In the plugin browser i can see the separate plugin (which already should have enabled cmyk image mode, no?), but not the separate+ plugin.

How can I get basic CMYK support please?

EDIT: Ubuntu-64bit system
EDIT2: According to [this post](http://www.openmutual.org/2011/08/converting-cmyk-psd-files-for-use-in-gimp/) from 2011, even with separate+ installed opening cmyk-psd files is not possible. Does this still hold true end 2013? He lists some alternatives which all are not satisfactory.

IMHO, already it is unfortunate for linux as a platform for artists, that cmyk support is not there out of the box in gimp, but at least the installation of the plugin should be easy.

thanks

Comment: +1 This is a highly relevant question and I have struggled with it myself several times lately without a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could reference the following wiki.

[CMYK support in The GIMP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CMYK_support_in_The_GIMP#About_CMYK_color_and_Gimp)

Although it is ArchLinux specific, it is helpful.